# Passing variable to a query in shell

Tags: shell, google-bigquery

I am running a code in shell

```
while read line;
do
  var="$(bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'select count(*) from `'$line'` ')"
  echo $var

  bq query --destination_table abc:Test_vik.view --use_legacy_sql=false --append 'select table_name,'+"$var" as Count,True as Is_backup,current_timestamp as Insert_Datetime from (select * from `abc.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS`) where table_name=  "'${line##*.}'"  '
done < count.txt
```

The out in the table is `${var}` instead of the count.

[image]

Comment: Can you check that the bq query line you posted is what you are actually using?

Comment: Yes, when i am using echo $var, i am getting count as 115. But when i am using it in the next query i am getting ${var}

Comment: As a test, place your bash code in a file (eg. myfile.sh) and begin the file with

#!/bin/bash ... and on a new line set -x and then the rest of your code.   Run the script and paste the results.  This will log bash debugging output.  I'm looking to see how the bq command is being expanded.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
while read line;
do
var="$(bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'select count(*) as count from `'$line'` ')"
echo $var
done < count.txt

I have tried this, still not working.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate your use case. And I have been able to pass a variable to a query through the shell. Particularly, I added to the code of vik_singh a removal of whitespaces which to me was creating problem in porting such variable. The code I ran is the following:

```
 1) var="$(bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'select text from `myproject.mydataset.mytable`' )"
    2) x="$(echo $var | cut -d'|' -f4 | tr -d '[:space:]')"
    3) bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'select text, time, current_timestamp from (select * from `myproject.mydataset.mytable` where text like  "'${x}'")  '
```

1) Particularly I have been querying a table with name of people and timestamps to get the names. 2) Then I parsed the result i wanted to ingest in the next query and cleaned it from redundant characters, saving it into a new variable x.
3) After I queried the new table with the conditional value specified in the x variable and it returned expected results

Perahps my suggestion would be to double check the syntax nearby such variable insertion. I hope this was useful to you

Answer (score 0):

var="$(bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'select count(*) as count from `'$line'` ')"
x="$(echo $var | grep count | cut -d'|' -f4)"